# 2D game world engine

Tags: c#, unity

I'am starting to develop a 2D game with snake or worm.

My question now is: When my snake reaches the right edge the world should move. (Like in [this game](http://www.snakeplaygame.org/snake-game/)) My first thought was to implement a camera and to create a huge image for the world. (e.g 4096 x 512). So I only have to move the camera to solve the problem.

Is that a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that, but if the image is just the same pattern repeated over and over, you are better off using a smaller texture with "texture repeat" since that will use less memory.  If your image varies and isn't just repeating, tiled graphics is also another good alternative to a single large texture.  Tiled graphics use small image tiles and set them down in a pattern of your choosing to make it look interesting.  But, a large texture isn't the end of the world, so your solution would work in a pinch too, yep.